# Executing a console jar file

Tags: java, jar, console, share, exe

I made a little console text-based game that takes in user input and what-not, and I was wondering if there was any other way to run it besides having to *navigate to its location in the CMD* and typing out the *java -jar name.jar* .

**So to be concise**: I want to know if there's anyway I can make a file that opens and immediately executes my program instead of having to do the steps above, so as to really be able to share it with my friends for example, like in a .exe or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd C:\Users\...\fileDirectory
java -jar name.jar
pause
```

save the above in a file `execute.bat` and double click it.

or you can just type

```
java -jar name.jar
pause
```

and say, that it must be in a folder with your jar.

Comment: This worked, however the window closes immediately after the program is terminated, so I don't have the chance to read what is printed just before the program closes. How can I fix this?

Comment: Add `pause` statement to `.bat` file.

Comment: @Steven add pause.

Comment: Everything worked fine, although adding "start" to the beginning in the bat file generated some problems, my program would open in its own CMD window and the pause would open in another CMD window. I got around this by removing "start" at the beginning, this executes my program and ends it with the pause, just like I needed! :)

Comment: Interesting. I'll remember that.

Answer (score 0):

`.bat` will not work on linux system. So optional you can create a runnable jar.

Every modern IDE like Eclipse, Netbean or Intellij can create a single runnable jar for you, so you can just double click it and start the application.

Comment: You're right, but the OP asks about CMD which is special for Windows

Comment: @xenteros I know it just a optional answer, because some friend could have linux or mac and so on. you know, write once run every where :)